# Why is package restore failing when I upgrade to ASP.NET Core 1.0.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am attempting to install ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 on my windows 7 dev box which already has ASP.NET Core 1.0 working in Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3.

To accomplish this I installed `.NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2` from https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows as indicated by https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/13/announcing-september-2016-updates-for-net-core-1-0/

I then updated several version numbers in my existing project.json file from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 so that my web application would use the new 1.0.1 components.

As expected this triggers a package restore, but unfortunately it fails.  I can't figure out why the packages restore is failing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Here are the errors from the output window:

Errors in C:\Users\Ron Clabo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\src\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\wwwGiftOasisResponsive.xproj
    Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.
PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe restore "C:\Users\Ron Clabo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\wwwGiftOasisResponsive.vs\restore.dg"
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\Ron Clabo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\src\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\project.json...
error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.
log  : Restoring packages for tool 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools' in C:\Users\Ron Clabo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\src\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\project.json...
log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\Users\Ron Clabo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\src\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\project.lock.json
log  : C:\Users\Ron Clabo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\src\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\wwwGiftOasisResponsive.xproj
log  : Restore failed in 2895ms.
Errors in C:\Users\Ron Clabo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\src\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\wwwGiftOasisResponsive.xproj
    Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration (>= 1.0.1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.

My understanding is that the upgrade from ASP.NET Core 1.0 to 1.0.1 is suppose to be pretty easy so I must be missing something simple but after hours of looking I could really use some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every package got version bumped to 1.0.1. There is no 1.0.1 version of IIS Integration [on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration/). That component should be left at 1.0.0 in your project.json.

Comment: What a perfect example of how one small mistake can cost a programmer hours of time.  Ug.  The fact that VS red underlined lots of the 1.0.1 occurrences rather than just for IISIntegration obscured my issue.  Thank you for finding it so quickly!

Answer (score 5):

You didn't read the [upgrade instructions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/09/13/asp-net-core-sept-2016-patch/) (and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases/tag/1.0.1)) correctly.

This is not a global version bump. Only the listed packages were upgraded to 1.0.1. All remaining ASP.NET Core packages stay at 1.0.0, this includes `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration`.

The affected packages are:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers! I upvoted since that's all I can do after accepting the other answer.